# Aggregate values of a column in a pandas df based on multiple filters of a different column - python2.7

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

Starting pandas df is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'event':['caller',  'X',  'y',   'X', 'caller', 'caller', 'z', 'z', 'X',  'X',  'w',  'X',  'y',  'X',  'z',  'caller'],
    'value':['c1',      'x1', 'yy', 'x2', 'c2',     'c3',     'zz', 'zz', 'x1', 'x2', 'ww', 'x3', 'yy', 'x4', 'z1', 'c4']
})
df
Out[24]: 
     event value
0   caller    c1
1        X    x1
2        y    yy
3        X    x2
4   caller    c2
5   caller    c3
6        z    zz
7        z    zz
8        X    x1
9        X    x2
10       w    ww
11       X    x3
12       y    yy
13       X    x4
14       z    z1
15  caller    c4
```

The goal is to aggregate all values where `event==X` in one single `value` that might be (or not!)  *for each section* where `event==caller` .

*Note** that:

1. `event == X` might be or not consecutive within a `caller` section.
2. there might be cases when `event == X` might not be at all in some of the `caller` section.
3. there might be duplicated cases like `event == z`. These should *not* be aggregated.

Thus, to keep it simple, only values where `event==X` which might appear anywhere within `caller` section should be aggregated.

The final *df*  (`df_aggr)  should look like this:

```
df_aggr = pd.DataFrame({
    'event':['caller',  'X',     'y',    'caller', 'caller', 'z', 'z', 'X',           'w',  'y',  'z',  'caller'],
    'value':['c1',      'x1 x2', 'yy',   'c2',     'c3',     'zz', 'zz', 'x1 x2 x3 x4', 'ww', 'yy', 'z1',  'c4']
})
df_aggr
Out[28]: 
     event        value
0   caller           c1
1        X        x1 x2
2        y           yy
3   caller           c2
4   caller           c3
5        z           zz
6        z           zz
7        X  x1 x2 x3 x4
8        w           ww
9        y           yy
10       z           z1
11  caller           c4
```

It has to work on python2.7 and `pandas=0.15.2` .

**UPDATE:**

-----Solution for `pandas=0.15.2`------

Based on David's answer, in case someone might need to support `pandas==0.15.2`, it had to be tweaked around to accommodate the differences between version.

```
In [36]: df = pd.DataFrame({
    ...:     'event':['caller',  'X',  'y',   'X', 'caller', 'caller', 'z', 'z', 'X',  'X',  'w',  'X',  'y',  'X',  'z',  'caller'],
    ...:     'value':['c1',      'x1', 'yy', 'x2', 'c2',     'c3',     'zz', 'zz', 'x1', 'x2', 'ww', 'x3', 'yy', 'x4', 'z1', 'c4']
    ...: })
    ...:
    ...: s = (df['event'] == 'caller').cumsum()
    ...: df['value'] = df['value'].where(df['value'].mask(df['event'] == 'X'), df.groupby(['event', s])['value'].transform(' '.join))
    ...: df = df[~((df.duplicated()) & (df['event'] == 'X'))].reset_index(drop=True)
    ...:

In [37]: df
Out[37]:
     event        value
0   caller           c1
1        X        x1 x2
2        y           yy
3   caller           c2
4   caller           c3
5        z           zz
6        z           zz
7        X  x1 x2 x3 x4
8        w           ww
9        y           yy
10       z           z1
11  caller           c4

In [38]:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Similar to Quang's approach, you can separate into 'caller' sections by using `cumsum()`. `cumsum` and `cumcount` are ever useful for categorization.
2. Then, use `mask` to conditionally `join` the grouped `value` if equal to `x` -- otherwise do nothing.
3. Finally, `drop_duplicates()`, as we haven't removed the extra row yet that was joined.

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'event':['caller',  'X',  'y',   'X', 'caller', 'caller', 'z', 'z', 'X',  'X',  'w',  'X',  'y',  'X',  'z',  'caller'],
    'value':['c1',      'x1', 'yy', 'x2', 'c2',     'c3',     'zz', 'zz', 'x1', 'x2', 'ww', 'x3', 'yy', 'x4', 'z1', 'c4']
})
s = (df['event'] == 'caller').cumsum()
df['value'] = df['value'].mask(df['event'] == 'X',
                               df.groupby(['event', s])['value'].transform(' '.join))
df = df[~((df.duplicated(keep='first')) & (df['event'] == 'X'))].reset_index(drop=True)
df

Out[1]: 
     event        value
0   caller           c1
1        X        x1 x2
2        y           yy
3   caller           c2
4   caller           c3
5        z           zz
6        z           zz
7        X  x1 x2 x3 x4
8        w           ww
9        y           yy
10       z           z1
11  caller           c4
```

Comment: It 'almost' works but it drops other duplicated case when `event != X`. For example,  values where `event == z` should be kept. I updated the post to make it more clear. Cheers!

Comment: It doesn't work with pandas that I have. I'm restricted to `pandas==0.15.2`.
It generates this error: `TypeError: mask() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)` .

Answer (score 0):

Use `cumsum` on check for `caller` to identify the session and groupby:

```
(df.groupby([df.event.eq('caller').cumsum(),
            'event'])['value'].agg(' '.join)
   .reset_index(level=1)
   .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

**Note** That will concatenate all `value` with the same `event` within a session, i.e. if you have two `z`, the two `value` for those rows will be concatenated. Throw `df.event.ne('x').cumsum()` in to `groupby` to group the blocks of `x` only:

```
(df.groupby([df.event.eq('caller').cumsum(),
            df.event.ne('x').cumsum(),
                  'event'
                 ])['value'].agg(' '.join)
   .reset_index(level=-1)
   .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

Output:

```
    event  value
0  caller     c1
1       x     x1
2       y     yy
3  caller     c2
4  caller     c3
5       x  x1 x2
6       z     z1
7  caller     c4
```

Comment: The solution is working only if `event==X` are consecutive events for fails for non-consecutive cases where `event==X`. I updated the post to reflect the more general case.